# How can I manipulate a copy of an array without changing the original array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array called n with numbers, and my goal is to make an array m where m[i] = n[i] - n[i-1]. m[0] is just equal to n[0]. I've tried this:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1,2,3,4])
m = n
for i in range(1, len(n)):
    m[i] = n[i] - n[i-1]
```

The assignment in the for loop does something I don't understand, because it makes both n and m into arrays = [1 1 2 2]. I simply want to change the inputs in m.

Note: My code does as I want it to when I strictly initialize both n and m like this:

```
n = np.array([1,2,3,4])
m = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

But I feel like I should be able to make a copy of n and be able to to manipulate ONLY the copy. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: In your original code, `m` is just another reference to the same array object `n` points to.
In your second version, `m` and `n` point to different array objects.

Comment: I see, so they're pointing to the same object. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `m = n`, you're simply binding a new name `m` to an existing array named `n`. That's why, when you later make changes to `m`, you see the same changes applied to `n`. They both refer to the same object in memory.

To make a copy of the array, you should use the `numpy.copy()` method:

```
m = np.copy(n)
```

Comment: `m = copy.deepcopy(n)`  is superior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `copy()` method to create a copy and not modify the original array as:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1,2,3,4])
m = n.copy()
for i in range(1, len(n)):
    m[i] = n[i] - n[i-1]
print(m)
print(n)
```

Output:

```
[1 1 1 1]
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: SO has the duplicate flag for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try "m is n" and you will see they are pointing to the same object, not a copy. Variables in Python are just pointers to the underlying objects, so in this example both m and n are pointing to the same array object and modifying it through either of its "names" modifies the same array. You need something like `m = n.copy()` I am not sure of the exact syntax in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Use fancy indexing and the power of numpy. Something like this may work

```
m= n.copy()
m[1:] = n[1:] - n[:-1]
#m[0] = n[0] # not needed because m is originally a copy of n
```

The `n[1:]` will create an array with the first element removed, before doing the array sum operation
`n[:-1]`  will create an array with the last element removed

Comment: The big advantage of numpy is that you don't need to use for loops in many of the array operations, and it is much faster this way